# Python Beautifulsoup find all function without duplication

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
markup = '<b></b><a></a><p>hey</p><li><p>How</p></li><li><p>are you </p></li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
data = soup.find_all('p','li')
print(data)
```

The result looks like this

```
['<p>hey</p>,<p>How </p>,<li><p>How</p></li>,<p>are you </p>,<li><p>are you </p></li>']
```

How can I  make it only return

```
['<p>hey</p>,<li><p>How</p></li>,<li><p>are you </p></li>']
```

or any ways that I can remove the duplicated p tags Thanks

Comment: do you mean beautifulsoup?

Comment: "soap", "soup".. "patato"... "pateto".... in coding all different results ahead expected. and it ain't vegies! Aaron.. fix the lingo ;-) End of reviewing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is not analyzing the text of the `html`, instead, it is acquiring the desired tag structure. In this case, you need to perform an additional step and check if the text of an `<p>` is already seen in a different structure:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
markup = '<b></b><a></a><p>hey</p><li><p>How</p></li><li><p>are you </p></li>'
s = soup(markup, 'lxml')
final_s = s.find_all(re.compile('p|li'))
final_data = [','.join(map(str, [a for i, a in enumerate(final_s) if not any(a.text == b.text for b in final_s[:i])]))]
```

Output:

```
['<p>hey</p>,<li><p>How</p></li>,<li><p>are you </p></li>']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the text and not the `<li>` tags, you can just search for the `<p>` tags and get the desired result without duplication.

```
>>> data = soup.find_all('p')
>>> data
[<p>hey</p>, <p>How</p>, <p>are you </p>]
```

Or, if you are simply looking for the text, you can use this:

```
>>> data = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('p')]
>>> data
['hey', 'How', 'are you ']
```